# Mozart K545, what is the correct fingering for the left-hand runs starting measure 50?

Tags: technique, fingering, mozart

Or maybe even broader, how do you choose fingerings for any given passage, especially with extended runs? I taught myself piano, so I don't know if there are any hard-and-fast techniques.

If I try to do this passage with my left hand using the same fingerings (reversed) as my right hand, then my fingers land awkwardly on some of the black keys, and there is no way to cross over my thumb to continue the phrase.

Thanks.

Comment: This would be better if you could include an image of the excerpt, and what fingerings you've tried.

Comment: The fingering I normally try is 5 4 3 2 1 3 2 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4. (1 is thumb, 5 is pinky) This is nice because it lands neatly back on the pinky, and required only one crossover in each direction, but it seems unnecessarily difficult for some of the phrases. This is also the same fingering I do for my right hand, but in reverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer broadly, studying traditional scale fingerings and technical sequences (like Hanon) will give you an intuitive sense of what fingerings to use in most situations.

I'm not really sure why you would expect the reverse of right hand fingerings to work for the left hand -- the keyboard itself is not symmetrical, so different fingering patterns are necessary. This will also become apparent after studying scales.

And to directly answer the question; I would suggest working from editions that include fingerings for you until you are experienced enough to come up with your own. This will help you develop good habits even if you don't understand the reasoning. Eventually you will need these less and less, or perhaps even find improvements that work better for you than what some editor came up with.

Comment: Thank you, funny enough, I ended up becoming comfortable with the original fingering after trying it a few more times. For me personally it's always easiest to do as few cross-overs as possible.

As far as good habits go though I think you're right, I will try to find pieces with fingerings indicated, since these kinds of problems come up way too often.

Answer (score 1):

Right, the first two measures are bad because the Bb screws with the otherwise obvious pattern (standard fingering but crossing under 4 on the way down to buy the extra note).  Several editions list the first two measures as:

5_43 2132 1231 2341 | 4_32 1432 1234 1234

I personally think this is over-complicated.  I hate the scrunch from 1 to 4 across the bar.  I would do the first measure as:

5_43 2132 1212 3123

And then continue as above.

Comment: Schirmer seems to indicate your suggested fingering.

Comment: It's actually the third measure that screws with me, because then the obvious pattern requires you to go 2 1 from A to Bb and cross back over, and to start the phrase with your left pinky on the lower Bb.

Answer (score 0):

The fingering 
5_43 2132 1231 2341 | 4_32 1432 1234 1234 
is apparently based on the logic that the first bar is an F major scale, so finger it like one. But starting with 5 won't give you a "natural" accent on the first beat of the bar. You could try
3-21 4321 3123 4123 | 4- etc. 
(I would prefer 3123 on the third beat rather than 2123, again to get a natural accent from the 3, but YMMV).

But starting the second bar with 4 is even weaker than 5, so try something like
3-21 4321 3121 2312 | 3- etc.
and then you can repeat the same fingering for each bar in the sequence.

But the best advice here is "get a teacher". We have no idea how big your hands are, and what standard your playing has reached. The "best" fingering for me (who first played this 40 years ago) is unlikely to be the "best" for you.

Comment: I have strong pinkies, so starting the phrase on 5 isn't an issue in terms of accenting the notes. I'm going to copy down and try your suggestions though.